# How to getting paths that are self-loops using GremlinPipeline?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

I'm working with a network that allows self-loops (i.e., some edges have the same vertex as both head and tail). Suppose, the graph `g` has 3 vertices (`adam`, `bill`, and `cid`), and 3 edges of type `reports` (`[adam-reports->bill]`, `[bill-reports->cid]`, and `[adam-reports->adam]`), the last being the only reflexive edge in this example.

```
gremlin> g = new TinkerGraph();
gremlin> adam = g.addVertex('adam');
gremlin> bill = g.addVertex('bill');
gremlin> cid = g.addVertex('cid');
gremlin> g.addEdge(adam, bill, 'reports');
gremlin> g.addEdge(bill, cid, 'reports');
gremlin> g.addEdge(adam, adam, 'reports');
```

In gremlin, the self-loop(s) can be easily retrieved, thus:

```
gremlin> g.V.sideEffect{v=it}.outE('reports').inV.filter{it==v}.path
gremlin> [v[adam], e[2][adam-reports->adam], v[adam]]
```

However, I'm trying to do the same using `GremlinPipeline` in Java without success. How can I build a valid GremlinePipeline to do the above?

```
GremlinPipeline pp = new GremlinPipeline();
// Add various pies to pp to get a valid pipeline
pp.setStarts(g.getVertices());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to find self-loop edges, do this:

```
g.E.filter{it.inV == it.outV}
```

Given you sample TinkerGraph above, the output is:

```
gremlin> g.E.filter{it.inV == it.outV}
==>e[2][adam-reports->adam]
```